# Scheduling an R Script

Tags: r, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

My team and I are using a .bat file

@echo off
"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" R CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users(user name)\Hello.R"

to execute a script that reads...

print("Hello World!")

When we run the .bat file, Rstudio opens, it presents the script, but it does not run the script automatically to present the final result in the counsel.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to run it with Rstudio or just R? Try this to run just the r language `C:\…...\R\R-3.6.1\bin\rscript.exe C:\......\Hello.R`.  This opens a desktop window, runs the script and then closes.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I did figure it out and ran it in R.exe, not Rstudio.exe.  Thanks for the help @Dave2e